# mysql: How to INNER JOIN a table but limit join to 1 result with the highest vote or count?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables. One is items and another is votes for those items.

```
Items table has: |item_id|name|post_date
Votes table has: |votes_id|item_id|answer|total_yes|total_no
```

What I want to do is show all items based on post_date and show the answer in the votes table with the HIGHEST total_yes. So I want to show only a SINGLE answer from the votes table with the highest total_yes vote.

I was trying:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM Items a
INNER JOIN Votes b ON a.item_id = b.item_id
GROUP by a.item_id
ORDER by a.post_date DESC, b.total_yes DESC
```

But that doesnt work.

The result I would like to see is:

```
<item><answer><yes votes>
Buick | Fastest | 2 yes votes
Mercedes | Shiny | 32 yes votes
Honda | Quick | 39 yes votes
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: najmeddine's answer is pretty close. But problem is if an item doesnt have a vote, then it's not shown. What I want to do is show all items (even if there's no vote in Votes table).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM Items a
       LEFT JOIN Votes b on a.item_id = b.item_id
                         and b.total_yes = (select max(total_yes) 
                                              from Votes v 
                         where v.item_id = a.item_id)
ORDER BY a.post_date DESC, b.total_yes DESC
```

N.B.: if you have for an item 2 answers with the same total_yes = max, you will have 2 rows for that item.

Comment: One issue... If table Votes does not have a matching item_id, then that Item is not shown. Anyway to do it such that if there is no join, it'll still show the item?

Comment: it just needs a LEFT JOIN. Done.

Comment: Man that's awesome!!! You saved me a lot of frustration. You can see the fruits of your contribution on my site (it's still not finished) at http://www.photoidentify.com

Comment: `ORDER BY a.post_date DESC, b.total_yes DESC` make query very slow if there is too many record (100,000), is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query :)

that will take only one record, but at the moment you're ordering by the date first, so you'll get the highest vote for the last date voted on.  Is that what you want?

If you want the highest total vote regardless you'll need to order by that first.

Comment: I actually want to show a bunch of results. And each result would show the highest vote. So it's a loop through the query. Thanks!

Comment: Scott, I hope you aren't putting a query inside of a loop. There should be a way to write your query so you retrieve all the results you need, without doing a loop. If you use a loop, you will run into synchronization issues, and possibly speed issues.