# Left Join with condition from join

Tags: mysql, left-join

Suppose I have 2 tables:

```
    Table_1 has |Product_ID|Max_Date
    Table_2 has |Invoice_ID|Product_ID|Sale_Date|Amount_Sold
```

Table_2 stores all the Sales for the products.

I want to join the tables in such a way that I get a SUM(Amount_Sold) from Table_2 grouped by Product_ID but only considering the sales that occured before the Max_Date for each product from Table_1.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Table_1)a 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Product_ID,Sale_Date,SUM(Amount_Sold) FROM Table_2 GROUP BY Product_ID)b
ON a.Product_ID=b.Product_ID AND b.Sale_Date<a.Max_Date
```

but it didn't return the correct sums.

I think the answer might be along these lines, but I have not been able to figure it out... 
[mysql: How to INNER JOIN a table but limit join to 1 result with the highest vote or count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425894/mysql-how-to-inner-join-a-table-but-limit-join-to-1-result-with-the-highest-vot)

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the date criteria in your join conditional, which also makes the joins simpler to read, IMHO.

```
SELECT t2.product_id, sum(amount_sold)
    FROM Table_1 t1 INNER JOIN Table_2 t2
    ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND t2.sale_date <= t1.max_date
    GROUP BY t2.product_id
```